# ZendFramework - How to get all the list of TLD to remove from website?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-filter, zend-filter-strip-tags

I have a long list with website address's. But i have to filter them and get only the part "abcd". In my cut/paste/algorithm i have very random format's of websites to deal, and dealing with large list is like very time consuming.

Example:

```
www.abcd.tld.tld.tld to abcd
http://www.abcd.tld.tdl to abcd
abcd.tld to abcd
abcd.tld.tld to abcd
http://abcd.tld to abcd
http://abcd.tld.tld to abcd
```

Which Zend_Filter i can ues tot cut front and tail, and always get the middle part of "abcd". Or is there any PHP built-in function which can do this?

Comment: The part to extract looks completely random to me. You might want to clarify the rules by which to extract.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem i got. I did split on DOT but because its so random i can not put that as final algorithm.

Comment: Hm, and `http://http.abcd.tld.tld`. `http://static.abcd.tld`. or `http://totalawesomerandomness.abcd.tld`?

Comment: @Wrikken: from your samples i have to `http` for 1st one, for second one  i have to get `static` and for the last one i have to get `totalawesomerandomness` + i have also some URL listed without `http://` or `www.` or `http://www.`

Comment: You mean to strip out _ccSLD_'s too, then the only thing I can think of is indeed listing all of those. Good luck, Brazil for instance [seems to have 67](http://registro.br/dominio/dpn.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with some basic string functions in PHP. Load all your URLs into a string variable and then do a simple `str_replace`

```
$old_urls; // load your urls into this variable
$search = array('http://','https://','www.','.com','.net','.us','.org','.edu','.us'); // etc, add more tlds
$new_urls = str_replace($search,'',$old_urls);
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: OK - that logic is fine. But there are many other sites i got which has .tld.tld. So what you are saying is collect all those TLD and make that array?

Comment: Certainly, you can expand on the `$search` array in the code by adding more elements ...`,'.tld','.tld2'`... to the array. It's definitely a down and dirty solution to what you are looking to do, but it should work just fine after you place all the '.tld's you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match('_https?://([a-z0-9-])\..*_i', $original_url, $matches);` should do you well.
`$matches[1]` should now contain the first section after `http(s)://` and before the first `.`.